# Rather than bubblesorting these names...the program crashes

Tags: c

I clearly am doing something wrong but, for the life of me, can't figure out what.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int done=0;
    int end=0;
    int didswap=0;
    char *temp[2] = {0};
    int i;
    int x;
    printf("This function Bubble sorts the Flintstones in alphabetical order!\n");
    printf("The Flintstones names are:\nFred\nBarney\nWilma\nPebbles\nDino\n");
    char *names[5] = {0};
    names [0] = "Fred";
    names [1] = "Barney";
    names [2] = "Wilma";
    names [3] = "Pebbles";
    names [4] = "Dino";
    while(end == 0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        { 
            if (strcmp(names[i],names[i+1])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp[0],names[i]);
                strcpy(temp[1],names[i+1]);
                strcpy(names[i],temp[1]);
                strcpy(names[i+1],temp[0]);
                didswap = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                didswap = 0;
            }
            done = done+didswap;
        }  
        if (done == 0)
            end = 1;
        else
            done = 0;
    }
    printf("When alphabetized they are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", names[i]);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Comment: Does it give you an error message?

Comment: Wow, a Bubble sort that is even slower than O^2 due to the entire string copy :)

Comment: No, no error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of string literals.  These may be held in read only memory so you can't change their content.  You can however change the order you store pointers to them in `names` by replacing

```
strcpy(temp[0],names[i]);
strcpy(temp[1],names[i+1]);
strcpy(names[i],temp[1]);
strcpy(names[i+1],temp[0]);
```

with

```
const char* tmp = names[i];
names[i] = names[i+1];
names[i+1] = tmp;
```

Comment: I tried this but it came up with the error invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Comment: @user2592484, Make the array hold `const char *`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
       strcpy(temp[0],names[i]);

       strcpy(temp[1],names[i+1]);

       strcpy(names[i],temp[1]);

       strcpy(names[i+1],temp[0])
```

`names` strings are string literals and string literals are immutable in C. Attempting to modifiy a string literal invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: so how to I make names not a string literal?